# How to pass values from controller to JavaScript chart

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am able to fetch profit and loss values for every month from my database and I have shown below how the responses for both profit and loss are displayed.

What I want to do now is to display the month and their respective figures in the chart in the script below for both profit and loss?

How do I achieve this?

**Controller**

```php
$profit= Account::selectRaw('month(date) as month, sum(amount) as amount')
          ->with(array('sector' =>  function($query){
            $query->where('type','Income');
          }))->whereHas('sector',function($query){
            $query->where('type','Income');
          })
          ->groupBy('month')
          ->get();

$loss= Account::selectRaw('month(date) as month, 
        sum(amount) as amount')
        ->with(array('sector' =>  function($query){
            $query->where('type','Expence');
        }))->whereHas('sector',function($query){
            $query->where('type','Expence');
        })
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->get();

return view(index, compact('profit','loss'))
```

**Reponse for both queries**

```
profit
    {"key":["August","September"],"value":["71145.00","891.00"]}

loss
    {"key":["August","September","October"],"value":["71145.00","891.00","900.00"]}
```

**View**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    var data = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        series: [{
            name: 'series-real',
            data: [200, 289, 263, 278, 320, 450],
        }, {
            name: 'series-projection',
            data: [240, 502, 360, 380, 505,],            
        }]
    };

});
```

Comment: Do you have any HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
labels: {!! json_encode($profit[0]) !!},
        series: [{
            name: 'series-real',
            data: {!! json_encode($profit[1]) !!},
        }, {
            name: 'series-projection',
            data: {!! json_encode($loss[1]) !!},            
        }]
    };
```

json_encode will return the JSON representation of a value so js can use it.